# Change Discord Bot Profile Picture with command in Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making my own discord bot in python with discord.py, and I want it to choose a random picture from a folder and set it as its new Profile picture. I know how to do the random choosing bit, but I want to know how to set it as the new profile pic or if it is even possible.

Comment: Please narrow your question down to a *specific programming problem*. Adding code you've tried and why it doesn't work is a good start. See [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `commands.Bot.user.edit()` to change a bot's avatar programmatically.
`select_random_image_path()` is just a function that randomly selects an image from a folder.

```py
with ​open​(​select_random_image_path(), "rb") as file:
    new_avatar​ ​=​ ​file​.​read​() 
    await ​bot.​wait_until_ready​() 
    await​ ​bot.​user​.​edit​(​avatar​=​new_avatar​)
```